# Find point farthest 'outside' of a finite 2-D line? Projection?

Tags: geometry

I could not find a suitable answer online, so I will try my luck here. Imagine I have a finite line in 2-D space, defined by its endpoints A and B. Now we assume there are several pairs of points, e.g. AP1 and AP2 or BP1 and BP2. I want to identify which of these points is farthest 'outside' the line.

I have an example image attached: 
[image]

In this example I want to identify point **AP1** and point **BP1**. Raw distance does not work as a measure, e.g. since point BP1 is actually closer to the line than point BP2. Maybe a projection onto the line might work? Do you guys have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: You start by associating $AP_1$ with $AP_2$ before the graphic, then switch to associating $AP_1$ with $BP_1$ after the graphic, then bring in $BP_2$ to the discussion. Now I have no idea where you are going with this...Could you clarify your problem and what it is you want?

Comment: @J.Galt: "Outside" has no standard meaning in this context. Let's assume for the moment that your segment is the interval $[a, b]$ on the $x$-axis. Is a point $(x, y)$ "inside" if $a \leq x \leq b$ and "outside otherwise?

Comment: @Paul & Andrew D. Hwang: Phrasing is an issue in this context, since distance is not a measure of what I want. I put 'outside' in quotations for a reason, so here's the best explanation I can come up with: If you draw a line at each of the endpoints perpendicular to the AB, you get an area enclosed between the two resulting lines. Points within are 'inside', points not between those two lines are 'outside'.

Comment: @J.Galt Did I get your task correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the equation of an infinitely long line passing through points A and B, using the two point form. Find its slope.
Find the equations of lines passing through the outside points perpendicular to the line through A and B. Find where the perpendicular lines intersect the extended AB line.
For the intersections that are not between A and B, find the distance from the associated outside point to the closer of A and B.
For intersections between A and B, find the distance between the intersection and the outside point.

Comment: That still considers BP1 closer than BP2, which is not what the OP said they want (despite the checkmark).

Comment: @Rahul I think you misread the question.

Comment: I don't think I did.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

To define the distance to the segment $S$, I would first try to find the closest point $y\in S$ regarding to the query point $x$.
$$
y(x) = \min_{y\in S} d(x, y)
$$
where $d$ is some distance, typically the Euclidean distance $d(x,y) = \lVert x - y \rVert_2$.

Then $d(x,y(x))$ would be the distance of $x$ to the segment $S$.

Finally one would need to pick the largest distance of all query points:
$$
M = \max_{x\in Q} d(x, y(x))
$$

**Implementation:**

First one determines the closest point on the line $L$ which contains the segment $S$ to the query point $x$.
A direction vector of $L$ is
$$
r = B - A 
$$
and a unit direction vector
$$
u = \frac{1}{\lVert r \rVert} r
$$
We want to find $y\in L$ with a decomposition
$$
y = x + x_n
$$
where $x_n$ is the part of $x$ normal to $L$, thus where $x_n \cdot u = 0$.

As $y$ can be parameterized as 
$$
y = A + t u
$$ 
we get the condition
$$
0 = (A + t u - x) \cdot u = (A - x) \cdot u + t  \iff \\
t = (x - A) \cdot u
$$
The point $y$ is on $S$, if $t \in [0, \lVert r \rVert]$.

So we get
$$
y(x) = 
\begin{cases}
A + t u & \text{if } t \in [0, \lVert r \rVert] \\
A & \text{if } t < 0 \\
B & \text{if } t > \lVert r \rVert
\end{cases}
$$

**Update:**

Looking at your defintion of "outside" this part of the plane seems characterized by the last two cases of the above case distinction.
So you can restrict your search for the farthest one to points $x$ with $t < 0$ or $t > \lVert r \rVert$.

[image]

The image above shows the segment $S$ between $A$ and $B$, the "inside" and "outside" regions. Half-circles of distance $1$, $2$ and $3$ and two example points $X$ and $X_2$ and their corresponding $Y = y(X)$ and $Y_2 = y(X_2)$.

So for $X$ the distance to $S$ is $d(X, A)=3.16$ and for $X_2$ the distance is $d(X_2, B)=2.83$. For this example $X$ would be the most far away outside point to $S$.